# Javascript: How do I post with the button

Tags: javascript, jquery, pug

So I have this in a jade file

```
button#register.btn.btn-warning(type="button") Register
```

and I have

```
$(function(){
    $("#register").on("click",function(){
        var $form = $("form");
        $form.attr("action", "/register");
        $form.submit();
    });
});
```

In another file in another directory public/javascript/register.js

I'm trying to make them link together so it could do a router.post function.

But so far the button I'm clicking on doesn't have any functionality.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: And, when and how you include the register.js?